# What is this thing? – What starts with tea

Tags: riddle, rhyme

What starts with tea
And has a ball
Lacks I and me
Is one for all?

> What is this thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to say

> team

> What starts with tea
> And has a ball

> Many team sports have a ball. Some examples are: rugby, football, baseball, and basketball. Hockey is the only exception I can think of.

> Lacks I and me

> There is no I in team. And the me is all jumbled up. The "no I in team" is a known phrase too.

> Is one for all?

> A team is the group acting as one for a common goal.

Comment: What kind of ball do you have in a puzzle-solving team?

Comment: A grand time, in the classical fashion.

Comment: a figurative ball, @Matsmath, as Going hamateur says

Comment: Ahh, I have never ever heard this expression: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ball#nav2 . Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: [Beg to differ on the no 'i' in team...](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=no+i+in+team&view=detailv2&&id=549A95A9964B5C6976282BF271C1A290034D4091&selectedIndex=0&ccid=BALFy7pH&simid=608054945203750159&thid=OIP.M0402c5cbba474fa8afbd8155060ddbd7H0&ajaxhist=0)

Answer (score 6):

> Golf.

What starts with tea

> You start playing at a tee, that sounds like tea
>  [image: tee]

And has a ball

> [image: golf ball]

Lacks I and me

> There are not letters "I", "M" or "E" in it.

Is one for all?

> Everyone can play golf, but only if they can afford it :D.
>  Or, as [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42430/what-is-this-thing-what-starts-with-tea/42431?noredirect=1#comment126652_42431) suggested, it may be a reference to "hole in one". (one for all sounds like that).  Which is the holly grail of golf.

Comment: Last line might be something to do with hole in one